# no puedo encontrar el elemento boton, selenium, python

Tags: python, web, selenium

ya intente de todo, por xpath, class_name, tag_name etc pero no puede encontrar este elemento, asi luce el html del elemento

```
<button class ="btn btn-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="submitBtn">Crear cuenta</button>
```

no se a que se debe que no pueda entrar si alguien me puede ayudar por favor, este es un ejemplo de mi codigo intentando encontrar el elemento

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='app']/div/footer/button").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a intentar ayudarte haciendo uso de una práctica poco vistosa.
Cuando me encuentro en casos parecidos a este, lo que suelo hacer es buscar todos los elementos que posean la misma `clase`. En tu caso puedes probarlo de asi:

```
for btn in self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.btn.btn-submit'):
    if btn.get_attribute('name') == 'submitBtn':
        print(btn.text)
        btn.click()
        break
```

De esa forma vas a buscar todos los elementos que posean `btn btn-submit`. Luego iterar en cada uno de los botones para encontrar el que posee el valor 'submitBtn' en el atributo `name`. Si por alguna razón todos los botones poseen el mismo valor en ese atributo, debes cambiar el if por `if btn.text == 'Crear cuenta'`.

Otra opción puede ser buscar todos los elementos `button`, y seguir la misma lógica:

```
for btn in self.driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button'):
    if btn.get_attribute('name') == 'submitBtn':
        print(btn.text)
        btn.click()
        break
```

Espero que te sirva para poder resolver tu inconveniente.

pd: El `break` lo puse para que no siga iterando una vez que clickea el elemento deseado, por que si existen más de 100 botones, sería poco eficiente que siga iterando cuando el trabajo ya está terminado.

Comment: muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

hace mucho tiempo que no uso selenium, pero te recomendaría en este caso usar find_element_by_name, en tu caso:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_name("submitBtn").click()
```

No recuerdo muy bien como funcionaba xpath, pero revisando un código mío viejo:

```
  ordenar = br.find_element_by_name('msg')
  ordena2 = ordenar.find_element_by_xpath("./table/thead/tr/th[@class='dat']")
  ordena3 = ordena2.find_element_by_xpath("./a")
  ordena3.click()
```

xpath lo usaba para discriminar dentro de un objeto previamente seleccionado, normalmente siempre buscaba por "name" o bien por "class_name", o bien "id", y luego ya dentro de él buscaba usando xpath.

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: ya tambien intente por name tambien pero no funciona, parece que la solucion esta a que no puedo acceder directamente al elemento y necesito entrar a otro elemento antes es lo que yo creo